# Setting the Dropdown as 'selected' in a JSTL For loop

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am basically looping through an Arraylist in a JSP page and I can successfully populate a Dropdown with options.

```
<select id="perm_bmi_stable" name="perm_bmi_stable" class="col-md-12 form-control">
    <optgroup label="Stability">
        <c:forEach items="${versions}" var="version">
            <option value="${version.versionName}"> ${version.versionName </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Now I need to set the proper value in the dropdown as **selected** depending on the value of the **version.versionName** value.

The Dropdown contains the following values after the for loop generates them:

- 1.0
- 2.0
- 3.0
- 4.0

If the value in the version.versionName is for example 2.0, I need the loop to set **2.0** as the dropdown's selected option.

How can I add this if condition to my for loop?

**I tried this, But it doesn't work:**

```
<option value="${version.versionName}" <c:if test="${versions[0].versionName == '${version.versionName}'}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>${version.versionName}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are not using expression language properly

${....} contains EL expressions not EL variables
and variables unlike String literals do not need quotes inside EL expressions

Therefore this will not work

```
<option value="${version.versionName}" <c:if test="${versions[0].versionName == '${version.versionName}'}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>${version.versionName}</option>
```

This should work.
Note: you might want to add quotes around the selected attribute to have a consistent notation

```
<option value="${version.versionName}" <c:if test="${versions[0].versionName == version.versionName}"> <c:out value='selected="selected"'></c:out></c:if>>${version.versionName}</option>
```

To improve readability you might want to get rid of the c:out tags if they are not strictly necessary and use the ternary operator

Note: in this case, if you want double quotes around the selected attribute you can create a var to use inside the EL expression not to create conflict between quotes

```
<c:set var="sel" value='selected = "selected"'>

<option value="${version.versionName}" "${versions[0].versionName == version.versionName ? sel : ''}"> ${version.versionName}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the help of Ternary operator

```
 <option value="${version.versionName}" ${versions[0].versionName == version.versionName?'selected=selected':''} >${version.versionName}</option>
```